# I get an Error - field can't be blank - when trying to destroy a database entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails, ruby, and web development in general, and I'm having trouble trying to remove an object from my database.

I get "1 error prohibited this debate from being saved: Proposition can't be blank"

when I call the destroy method of the object.

This is my link:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete this debate', debates_path, :method => :delete %>
```

and this is my destroy method:

```
def destroy
  Debate.find(params[:id]).destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(debates_path) }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  end
end
```

If the debate is being destroyed anyway, why do I still get an error when the proposition is blank?

Edit:

The model for the debate:

```
class Debate < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :proposition, :presence => true

   has_many :responses, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I'm following the tutorial from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: @nash done. Can't believe I forgot to include them in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete this debate', debate, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: needed an @ in front of debate but this is what I needed. Thanks!